# R: create a dataframe from two lists

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following object, called `elements`, looking like this:

```
$A
$A$stringValue
[1] "A1,A2,A3,A4"

$B
$B$stringValue
[1] "B1,B2"
```

I've tried unlisting the object and getting a list with `A1,A2,A3,A4` and `B1,B2`, but I can't convert them to a dataframe after that. My desired output would be a dataframe looking like this:

```
Element    SubElements
      A             A1
      A             A2
      A             A3
      A             A4
      B             B1
      B             B2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
setNames(
  rev(stack(lapply(lst, function(x) unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), ","))))),
  c("Element", "SubElements")
)
```

which gives

```
  Element SubElements
1       A          A1
2       A          A2
3       A          A3
4       A          A4
5       B          B1
6       B          B2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution using lapply and melt (reshape package). It gives you the desired output, @ThomasIsCoding was first, but still I wanted to contribute :)

```
output=reshape::melt(lapply(elements,function(x) strsplit(unlist(x),",")))
output$L2=NULL
colnames(output)=c("Element", "SubElements")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L <- list( A = c( "A1,A2,A3,A4"),
           B = c( "B1,B2" ) )
           

library( data.table )
rbindlist( lapply( L, strsplit, "," ), idcol = "Element" )

#    Element V1
# 1:       A A1
# 2:       A A2
# 3:       A A3
# 4:       A A4
# 5:       B B1
# 6:       B B2
```